# javascript changing the shape of INPUT to select

Tags: javascript, select, input

Hello I am a beginner in this field who is also from Ukraine and therefore it is very difficult to find a possible existing answer to my question on the website, please do not criticize.

Tell me if there was java script allows you to change the shape of INPUT SELECT in.
Why do it.

The site with the addition of a material generating a form

which is not possible to change
 
but it is possible to change the page itself

that need to be replaced by this

```
<select id="drF11" class="manFlOth2" name="other2">
<option value="0" style="color:#A3A3A3">- Text0 -</option>
<option value="Text1">Text1</option>
<option value="Text2">Text2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the shape you want to change `<input type="text" id="drF11" class="manFlOth2" size="35" style="width:100%;" name="other2" value="" maxlength="100">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to replace `input` with `select`

You may try something like this

```
var textInput = document.getElementById('drF11');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<select id="drF11" class="manFlOth2" name="other2">' +
                '<option value="0" style="color:#A3A3A3">- Text0 -</option>' +
                '<option value="Text1">Text1</option>' +
                '<option value="Text2">Text2</option>' +
                '</select>';

textInput.parentNode.replaceChild(div.firstElementChild, textInput);
```